# how does page size and page works in get Customer assets works in thingsboard rest api?

Tags: thingsboard

guys, I m using thingsboard for the project I have a problem with getting my customers assets through rest API but my problem is with these new parameters before the update of API there was a limited for getting the number of assets but in new API they updated limited with page and page size I want to know what are these here is the API:
[image: api]

Answer (score 1):

Those are typical pagination parameters.

Assuming there are 1337 assets you would send *individual* requests with

pageSize=500 && page=0 to get assets 0 to 499;

pageSize=500 && page=1 to get assets 500 to 999;

pageSize=500 && page=2 to get assets 1000 to 1336